# Size of Icon feature is calculated wrong

Tags: openlayers-3

I am currently writing an implementation where the user is able to upload a blueprint and place it on the map.

Problem is that the icon feature is registered as a sub-extent of the actual image-extent.

When full image is shown all is good:
https://s24.postimg.org/lj3xmgsj9/image.png

When I move the map to the left, the image disappears as soon as the tie-fighter starts to leave the view:
https://s23.postimg.org/4p2tu0c5n/image.png

This is a problem since my users will have to be able to zoom in at the corners of their uploaded blueprint.

The following URL shows a working implementation is OL2:
http://gis.ibbeck.de/ginfo/apps/OLExamples/OL27/examples/ExternalGraphicOverlay/ExternalGraphicOverlay.asp
Here everything works great.

Is this a bug in OL3 or am I doing something wrong?
Switching to OL2 is not an option as we already have a lot of OL3 code.

The following code was used:
(drag, rotate, scale was removed to make a minimum working example)

```js
    var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            }),
            new ol.layer.Vector({
                source: new ol.source.Vector({
                    features: [
                        new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point([1389519.3624186157, 7496787.364362017]))
                    ]
                }),
                style: new ol.style.Style({
                    image: new ol.style.Icon({
                        src: 'https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/millennium-falcon-4_9c006047.jpeg',
                        scale: 0.75
                    })
                })
            })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            center: [1389519.3624186157, 7496787.364362017],
            zoom: 18
        })
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/build/ol.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have larger icons, you will have to set the `renderBuffer` property of [ol.layer.Vector](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.layer.Vector.html) (default: 100px), so that OpenLayers includes the feature even though the actual geometry is outside the view extent.

```
new ol.layer.Vector({
    renderBuffer: 600,
    ...
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nptq3hjy/